# Spring Boot Jackson: How to remove nulls from java array?

Tags: java, arrays, spring-boot, serialization, jackson

In my Spring Boot application when a class is written by me and I want to exclude `null` values from the object of that class while serialization, I just annotate the class with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` or alternatively I assign the property `spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=NON_NULL` in my properties file.

But now I have a controller which returns a Java Array(not a `Collection`) of my class as:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/reviews", method = GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Review[] searchReviews(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
```

And many a times this array is not full in which case I get `null` for the position where there is no item.

How can I tell Jackson to omit null values present inside a Java array when serializing it?

I just gave it a shot by putting the annotation on top of my controller method like this:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@RequestMapping(path = "/reviews", method = GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Review[] searchReviews(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
```

and this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/reviews", method = GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL) Review[] searchReviews(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {
```

This does not give any error, but doesn't work either.

Tried with setting the property in properties file, didn't work.

Searched the [github documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/serialization-Features) for Jackson serialization features, but found nothing that enables omitting `null` values from Java array while serialization. The closest feature is `write_empty_json_arrays`, but that is not what I need.

Does the fact that java array needs to be of fixed length has to do something with this?

What shall I do to convert a java array: `[object1, object2, null]` of size 3 to `[{}, {}]` instead of `[{}, {}, null]`?

Comment: Just do the right thing, and stop returning partially populated arrays. Don't even return arrays at all. Return a List<Review> (or a Set<Review>). Doing things right helps. You shouldn't try to tweak Jackson to compensate for the design problems in your code. You should rather fix the design problems.

Comment: not sure about jackson but you can use java 8 streams to filter the array where values != null and then collect the stream back to an array

Comment: @JBNizet why is this not a right thing? My requirement is to return top 20 reviews. I return the array with 20 reviews. If there are not enough reviews null is present in the array. I can do this using `List<Review>` but before doing that I am curios to know why is this not a right thing. Can you give some insight?

Comment: Because when an API returns an array of reviews, a client expects to get back an array containing reviews. Not an array where half of the elements are reviews and the other half is null, and where the client thus has to count the number of non-null elements to know how many reviews it actually contains (instead of just using list.size()), and has to add null checks everywhere to avoid NPEs, which wouldn't be needed if the API returned a list of non-null reviews in the first place.

Comment: Would you be happy if you went to a store to buy eggs, and you had to open every egg box to check that it actally contains 6 eggs as expected, and not 2 or 4 or 5? No. The store does the right thing, and makes sure each egg box it sells is a full box, containing 6 eggs.

Comment: Ok, even my question is same: I do not want null to be present there in the response. But I got your point that instead of expecting Jackson to do this for me, I should not have null in the first place.

Comment: *I do not want null to be present there in the response*: well, return a List<Review> containing only non-null reviews, and you won't have any null in the response. As simple as that.

Comment: @JBNizet got it. Updating the logic. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely change the business logic not to return an array with `null` values. Alternatively, you can filter out `null` vaues from the resultant array with Java 8's stream, e.g.:

```
Review[] reviews = //result;
return Arrays.stream(reviews)
   .filter(r -> r != null)
   .toArray(Review[]::new);
```